# Combine multiple observables in to a single RxJS stream

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

It appears I am lacking knowledge on which RxJS operator to resolve the following problem:

In my music application, I have a submission page (this is like a music album). To load the submission, I use the following query:

```
this.submissionId = parseInt(params['album']);

if (this.submissionId) {
  this.submissionGQL.watch({
    id: this.submissionId
  }).valueChanges.subscribe((submission) => {
      //submission loaded here!
  });
}
```

Easy enough! However, once I've loaded the `submission`, I have to load some auxiliary information such as the current `user` (to check if they are the artist of the submission) and `comments`. In order to avoid nested subscriptions, I can modify the above query to use `switchMap` to switch the query stream to `user` and `comments` observables once the `submission` resolves:

```
// stream to query for the submission and then switch query to user
this.submissionGQL.watch({
    id: this.submissionId
  }).valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap(submission => {
    this.submission = submission;
    return this.auth.user$
  })
).subscribe((user) => {
  // needs value of submission here
  if (user.id == this.submission.user.id) {
    //user is owner of submission
  }
})

// stream to query for the submission and then switch query to comments
this.submissionGQL.watch({
    id: this.submissionId
  }).valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap(submission => {
    this.comments$ = this.commentsGQL.watch({
      submissionId: submission.id //needs submission response here
    })
    return this.comments$.valueChanges
  })
).subscribe((comments) => {
  this.comments = comments;
})
```

Great! I've avoided the nested subscription issue BUT now...the first part of each `submission` request is identical. Basically, once, the `submission` is queried, i want to launch off two parallel queries:

- a query for the user
- a query for the comments

Which RxJS operator can perform such an operation? I suppose the subscribe at the end would emit an array response like:

```
.subscribe([user, comments] => {
    // check if user == submission.user.id here
    // also assign comments to component variable here
})
```

I believe `mergeMap` is sort of what I need but I'm not sure how to implement that properly. Or is this a case where I should `share()` the submission query and then build off my parallel queries separately? I'm very curious! Please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RxJS [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator for this scenario. As stated on the documentation,

> When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

```
const userQuery$ = this.submissionGQL.watch({
    id: this.submissionId
  }).valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap(submission => {
    this.submission = submission;
    return this.auth.user$
  })
)

// stream to query for the submission and then switch query to comments
const commentsQuery$ = this.submissionGQL.watch({
    id: this.submissionId
  }).valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap(submission => {
    this.comments$ = this.commentsGQL.watch({
      submissionId: submission.id //needs submission response here
    })
    return this.comments$.valueChanges
  })
)

forkJoin(userQuery$, commentsQuery$).subscribe([user, comments] => {
  // check if user == submission.user.id here
  // also assign comments to component variable here
})
```

Comment: I agree that `forkJoin` would work in the above scenario. However, I guess I was trying to see if it would be possible to not have to subscribe to `submissionGQL` twice. Does that make sense? Is that even feasible?

Comment: @JordanLewallen hmmm.. technically speaking you are only subscribing to it once, just that there are 2 different pipelines to handle this process. I am not sure how can we join it into a single pipelines though.. Nonetheless, I do believe that using `forkJoin` or `combineLatest` would be the most elegant solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  this.submissionGQL.watch({
    id: this.submissionId
  }).valueChanges.pipe(
   switchMap(submission => {
     this.submission = submission;
     const user$ = this.auth.user$;
     this.comments$ = this.commentsGQL.watch({
       submissionId: submission.id 
     });
     return combineLatest(user$, this.comments$);
   }),
   // maybe put a takeUntil to remove subscription and not cause memory leaks
  ).subscribe(([user, comments]) => {
    // check if user == submission.user.id here
    // also assign comments to component variable here
 });
```

Something you should consider is eliminating instance variables with the help of the `async` pipe given by Angular (https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/).
It will subscribe to the observable, present it into the view and automatically unsubscribe when the view is destroyed.

So, using that, we can get rid of `this.submissions = submission` by putting:

```
submissions$: Observable<ISubmission>; // assuming there is an interface of ISubmission, if not put any

// then when this.submissionId is defined
this.submissions$ = this.submissionGQL.watch({
  id: this.submissionId
}).valueChanges;

// then when using it in your view you can do {{ this.submissions$ | async }}
```

The same thing can go for `this.comments$`. All of this is optional though. I try to minimize instance variables as much as possible when using RxJS because too many instance variables leads to confusion.

Then you can lead off of `this.submissions$` observable and subscribe for the other main stream.

```
 this.submission$.pipe(
  switchMap(submission => ..... // everything else being the same
 )
```

I chose the `combineLatest` operator but you can use `zip` and `forkJoin` as you see fit. They all have subtle differences (https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom).

Comment: thanks for answering the other question too! Trying to implement both now and will get back

Comment: Also, in terms of instance variables, I guess in this case renaming to `this.submission$` wouldn't be smart...right? because my observable is returning a `combineLatest` of user and comments, not a submission object.

Comment: It depends, you can do as you see fit. When I say you can get rid of `this.submissions = submission`, I assume `this.submissions` is used in the HTML. My whole tangent of using the `async` pipe is my "political view" of what I think is cleaner code. My "political view" changes over time and I think this is good, it should for everybody. Also, I may have not understood your question entirely. It can be tough over text.

Comment: oh wait, so if I understand correctly, you are creating an instance variable of `this.submission$` and assigning it to the `submissionsGQL` observable. This request is triggered when using the async in html like: `submission$ | async`. BUT  also... in my component, you are saying to pipe `this.submission$` to use with `switchMap` to get the data for `comments` and `user`. Wouldn't this still mean that we would still have two queries of `submissionGQL`? (one triggered from the async html pipe and the other from the switchMap)? Or am i thinking about this wrong

Comment: ok so i just tested my theory above and surprisingly...it doesn't trigger the submissionGQL twice and...I don't quite know why. My understanding of `switchMap` is that it triggers the observable (in this case the `submissionGQL`) and then kills it before switching to the new observable (in this case the `combineLatest`). I'm using Apollo for GraphQL, so I'm not sure if it's because it's batching the request as one or this is just how observables are supposed to work

Comment: I think it's Apollo checking cache first before making the request again since parameters are identical

Comment: I think you're right though, it should do two requests and maybe Apollo is caching. Continue playing around and you will get better and better.